# How can I get value from custom field in Joomla 3.8.5?

Tags: joomla3.8.5

I had created the new fields in User:Fields named departments, phone, and mobile phone. How can I view it at my site like how username and email can be viewed? For now I'm using getUser() and getParam(), but only name, username, and email appeared. Where can I get the field name in Joomla? Please excuse my knowledge as I'm very new to Joomla. Thank you.

```
$registered = JAccess::getUsersByGroup(2); //change number in the brackets
$rows = '';

foreach($registered as $user_id) //loop every user exist
{
    echo "<br>";
    $user = JFactory::getUser($user_id);

    $rows .= '';
    $rows .= '' . $user->name . '';
    $rows .= '' . $user->username . '';
    $rows .= '' . $user->getParam('com_fields_departments') . '';
    $rows .= '' . $user->getParam('com_fields_phone') . '';
    $rows .= '' . $user->getParam('com_fields_mobile_phone') . '';
    $rows .= '' . $user->email . '';
    $rows .= '';    
}
echo $rows;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not do it like this, because that's responsibility of another component and not of the user Model/Class.

Use something like:

```
JLoader::register('FieldsHelper', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_fields/helpers/fields.php');
$fields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_users.user', $user, true);
array_map(function($field)use(&$user){
    $prop = str_replace('-','_',$field->name);
    $val = $field->value;
    $user->$prop = $val;
},$fields);
```

---

That's on fly produced example that is born from the code that worked for me at another project (initial code below)

```
JLoader::register('FieldsHelper', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_fields/helpers/fields.php');
$events = array_map(function($event){
    $event->images = (new Joomla\Registry\Registry())->loadString($event->images);
    $fields = FieldsHelper::getFields('com_content.article', $event, true);
    array_map(function($field)use(&$event){
        $prop = str_replace('-','_',$field->name);
        $val = $field->value;
        $event->$prop = $val;
    },$fields);
    return $event;
},$events);
```